# Lightweight cross-platform way to prompt for a file

Tags: python, dependencies, cross-platform, py2exe

I found a very built-in and easy way to prompt a system-specific nice open file dialog:

```
import Tkinter
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
tk_root = Tkinter.Tk()
tk_root.withdraw()

result = askopenfilename(
    filetypes=[("Foos", "*.png")],
)
```

However, this is way too heavy a dependency in terms of size. I'm packaging my app with py2exe and the app is **7 megabytes** bigger for having to include `Tkinter`. Surely there must be a simpler way to prompt a native file dialog that works on Windows, Mac, and Linux?

Comment: Does your app use any other graphical toolkit? Is it a command-line or windowed app?

Comment: @jozzas: It uses pygame, so it's a windowed app. It just has the one pygame window.

Answer (score 1):

There is a C library designed to perform this function, which could be wrapped in python.

https://github.com/mlabbe/nativefiledialog

Not sure what limitations the py2exe format imposes but I think this could be packaged into a pip wheel for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a pygame app, there's a project called [`Pygame Utilities`](http://code.google.com/p/pgu/) which has cross-platform support for file dialogs, among many other things. It appears to be fairly lightweight.

Doesn't look to be very well documented, though. If you download the package, run the `setup.py` file in the docs directory to generate the documentation.

Comment: Hmm this looks like someone implemented a file-chooser in Pygame... what I'm really looking for is a 'native' file browser. Like in Windows it would use explorer, on Mac it would use the Finder, etc. This is what the tkintre one seems to do, unless I'm mistaken and they just put a ton of effort into mimicking exactly each one on each platform?

Comment: That's what TKinter is doing. Some alternatives to it are wxPython (wxWidgets) and Qt, both of which can do exactly what you want, but neighter of which are lightweight - I'd think that Tkinter would be the smallest of those three.

Comment: Hmm... there's no standard "open file dialog" on Windows? For example, this [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Then I'd just have to hook into the DLL somehow... brilliant, I could use `pywin32` for that, but then I have to implement it differently for Mac, etc.. I was hoping someone else had done the work. But if not maybe I can do it & release the module.